# Unable to connect to postgres with node.js via SSL (unsupported protocol)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, openssl

I'm able to connect to the postgres instance via pgAdmin with the same credentials but I can't connect from my node.js server. I'm running the latest node version installed via Homebrew on my mac.

```
import { Client } from 'pg'
const config = {
    user,
    host,
    database: DATABASE,
    password,
    port: 5432,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/postgresql.key').toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/postgresql.crt').toString(),
    };
}

const client = new Client(config)
client.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
```

This is the error I get when calling `connect`:

`Error: write EPROTO 4499043776:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:`

I tried connecting to the host via openssl with the following command and it seems to connect.

`openssl s_client -starttls postgres -connect <ip>:5432`

```
...
Peer signing digest: MD5-SHA1
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: DH, 1024 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4437 bytes and written 511 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 67F98918A51486780EE40B6F2430310A04CBE141AEC7A78C09EAAC1B6AD62E52
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C296DD7EAD31580A7D1B3688DA170C3861F5F35755F93BC2A90CACAD7C640B761764C446797475892D785B6A37D278EE
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c8 c2 49 99 40 4b ed f7-e2 d5 61 6d 3d dc 3a 15   ..I.@K....am=.:.
    0010 - 80 b8 31 c8 9a e0 cd 2c-57 90 5a ed 10 aa 3a c7   ..1....,W.Z...:.
    0020 - eb 61 59 c4 d8 b0 ab 05-16 f5 b7 35 42 dc e8 d5   .aY........5B...
    0030 - c9 06 38 b6 e9 fd 81 bd-ad bc 56 30 e2 92 a7 89   ..8.......V0....
    0040 - a6 30 0b bc 71 a7 3d 63-90 ec fc f0 b2 ca 3f 0a   .0..q.=c......?.
    0050 - 44 4c 57 b3 9f 0c 7f 05-3a 78 6d 90 bc 37 3d 17   DLW.....:xm..7=.
    0060 - a4 0b 53 25 c4 d6 88 4b-a1 f2 57 31 07 21 bf 78   ..S%...K..W1.!.x
    0070 - 14 b3 93 60 a6 e9 ba 16-0e 48 d1 42 4e 8a e9 83   ...`.....H.BN...
    0080 - 53 c0 fe 7e 65 29 e4 e6-02 81 39 aa 3d 3e 0a 9b   S..~e)....9.=>..
    0090 - c2 a9 17 5a 34 c8 21 3c-9c 96 44 84 d1 48 c8 21   ...Z4.!<..D..H.!

    Start Time: 1582830738
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

Comment: "unsupported protocol" means that the SSL/TLS version that client is trying to connect with is not supported.  Most likely is because it's too old.  You will have to look into what the client version of SSL/TLS it's supporting (maybe the version of opensll library it uses?).  You may also need to specify the version you wish to connect with?

Comment: From what I can tell node.js includes openssl and node 13.8.0 is using the latest openssl. The server is not under my control though so I don't know anything about its capabilities.

Comment: My guess would be that the client config is not correct to successfully connect to the server.  I'm not a node person, so I think the best thing is for you to look into that options are available in the config setup and try to set it to what the server likes.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is that the only protocol the server supports is TLSv1 so the `unsupported protocol` error was stemming from the client code attempting to use something else newer not something that was too old.

I needed to use `secureOptions` in the ssl portion of the config to force it to TLSv1.

```
const config = {
    user,
    host,
    database: DATABASE,
    password,
    port: 5432,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/postgresql.key').toString(),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/postgresql.crt').toString(),
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3,

    };
}
```